# How do I make my table body width equal to the table width in HTML?

Tags: html

How do I make my table body width equal to the table width in HTML?

Comment: Can you post some code and styles please?

Answer (score 1):

You might also try setting the border-collapse style on your table to "collapse".  This will minimize any padding on the table created by the browser defaults.

```
table {
     border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For both your table and the body:

Check your margins, should be 0. Check your padding, should be 0 too. Check your styling ([Firebug](http://getfirebug.com)) to make sure it is what you think it is. Post your HTML and CSS if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume for the purpose of this answer that your HTML is like such:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            table.onetable {
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #F00;
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table class="onetable">
            <tr>
                <td>Hello World</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The reason why your table isn't filling the `body` is because your browser's default style imposes a padding to your `body` tag (usually 8px on most user-agents). Use the following CSS to override that style:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```